# Не вижу ошибки в синтаксисе sql; не получается задать primary key

Tags: sql

Столкнулась с тем, что не работает SQL-запрос, указывая на ошибки в синтаксисе.

```
CREATE TABLE dept (
  dept_id INTEGER, 
  dname VARCHAR(20)); 

CREATE TABLE emp (
  emp_id INTEGER, 
  ename VARCHAR (15), 
  salary NUMERIC (6,2);
```

Скормила пяти компиляторам код преподавателя (привожу ниже), тоже указывают на ошибки в синтаксисе.

```
CREATE TABLE person_info (
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
            first_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
                last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        gender CHAR(1),
        birthday DATE,
        salary NUMERIC(7,2)
        );
```

Я ошибок не вижу. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Вторая часть вопроса в том, что невозможно добавить primary key, даже копируя варианты, представленные в интернете.

Пробовала, например, `ALTER TABLE dept ADD PRIMARY KEY (dept_id);`

Если подскажете, в чем может быть проблема, будет здорово!

Comment: `emp` - пропущена скобка. Остальные два запроса - корректны (во всяком случае с точки зрения MySQL). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9cd74baa22b30a9898f6816ba163c6f0

Comment: @Akina спасибо!

Comment: @Akina А почему может не приниматься вот такой синтаксис в попытке сразу создать таблицу с первичным ключом? create table dept (
    dept_id  int(10) unsigned not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dname VARCHAR(20),
    primary key (dept_id);

Comment: Скобки посчитайте, да... PS. Совет - когда пишете что-то со скобками, то, дойдя до скобки, сразу ставьте обе, потом курсор на шаг назад, и продолжайте.

Comment: @Akina Совет хороший, спасибо!